# Access SOCKS5 proxy using HTTP header

Tags: java, .net, c++, proxy

If I am making a proxy factory, can I just make the outgoing request saying `Proxy::HTTP` (there's a similar enum for SOCKS) and the SOCKS5 proxy server should automatically detect and handle that correctly, right?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your tags are confusing and don't help to categorize this.  I don't think this should be tagged as "c++" and "java" and ".net."  I could see "c++" and ".net" if you were doing Windows C++ programming but even that wouldn't be correct. Can you perhaps select the one language you are asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense. A SOCKS proxy will expect to be spoken to via the SOCKS protocol. An HTTP proxy will expect to be spoken to via the HTTP CONNECT protocol. There's no question of getting the proxy type wrong at the client and the proxy server magically correcting that for you.